# Read file with (mostly) numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, parsing, split

The format is:

```
0
995

112
// there is an empty line here too
```

So, I am doing:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    articles = f.readlines()
for article in articles:
    article = int(article.split()[0])
```

but I am getting:

> IndexError: list index out of range

which I think comes from accessing `[0]` of the lines that do not have a number. How to find that (I interesting in identifying the empty line, because it means that collecting the current list should stop and being prepared for the next one).

```
print articles
['0 \n', '995 \n', '\n', '112 \n', '\n']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open(in.txt) as f:
    articles = [int(line) for line in f.read().splitlines() if line]
```

If you use `splitlines` instead of `readlines`, the `\n` chars will be removed for you so you just need to check for empty strings

Also, this list comprehension I used above is needed to store the result in the `articles` variable. The way you were doing, you overwrite the `article` variable each time and nothing gets saved.

To separate the blocks in several lists, do this:

```
with open(in.txt) as f:
    article = []
    articles = [article]
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            article = []
            articles.append(article)
            continue
        article.append(int(line))
```

Comment: Well JBernardo cool solution, but it doesn't address the question completely. You see I want to put 0 and 995 in a list and 112 in another one, so I want to know when the empty line came!

Comment: @gsamaras It will require you to write a little more (check updated answer).

Comment: Almost there JBernardo! Now this will generate an empty last list (for the last empty line I guess). Instead of `[[0, 995], [112]]` I am getting `[[0, 995], [112], []]`.

Comment: I would recommend against `f.read().splitlines()` (reads whole file into memory at once) when you can just do `for line in f`

Comment: @jamylak OP was using `readlines`... so the file must be small. The updated code do not read the full file

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend doing it this way:

```
numbers = []
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
          line = line.split()
          try:
               numbers.append(int(line[0]))
          except IndexError as e:
               pass
print numbers
```

Comment: lemme know if you'd like an explanation on anything

Comment: Your code Seekheart is self explaining! Thanks, if it wasn't for Michal's speed to post an answer first, I might have selected your answer. Next time ;)

Comment: lookin forward to it buddy :)

Comment: I like the code Seekheart and I am curious. I seem to have a prejudice against catching exceptions intentionally when I can just check for something and use exceptions to catch exceptional stuff. I avoid them otherwise.  So my question does this way have any obvious down sides?

Comment: Not really, since from my experience it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission (pythonic way of thinking).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether your split returns something before trying to access an element in it.

```
temp = article.split()
if temp: #returns false if temp == []
    article = int(article.split()[0])
```